# Why doesn't environment variable get updated in script

Tags: windows, cmd

I am basically a Linux guy forced into a Windows world lately, so I need to write a bat script, but I ran into the following problem.

Here is my .bat script

```
///////////////////////////
echo.
echo This is testbat script
echo -----------------------------------------------------------
echo.  

if "%1"=="" (
    echo "You did not enter an argument
) else (

    set "myvar="
    echo Argument is %1% 
    set myvar=%1%
    if "%myvar%"=="%1%" (
        echo myvar is %myvar%
    ) else (
        echo myvar is not set to %1
    )   
)
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

It seems that I need to run this script twice to get myvar to change.

For example, 
FIRST RUN:

> testbat.bat hello

OUTPUT:
          This is testbat script
          -----------------------

```
      Argument is hello
      myvar is not set to hello
```

SECOND RUN:

> testbat.bat hello

OUTPUT:
          This is testbat script
          -----------------------

```
      Argument is hello
      myvar is hello
```

NOW CHANGE the argument to bye
THIRD RUN:

> testbat.bat bye

OUTPUT:
          This is testbat script
          -----------------------

```
      Argument is bye
      myvar is not set to bye   (In fact, it is still hello here)
```

FOURTH RUN (same input as THIRD):

```
     > testbat.bat bye
```

OUTPUT:
          This is testbat script
          -----------------------

```
      Argument is bye
      myvar is bye    (Finally gets updated)
```

////////////////////////////////////

My question is why the script doesn't update the environment variable the first time?
Why do I need to run the script a second time to get the variable to change to the new value in the script?   I used the SET command and discovered that the value is changed in the environment, why does the script output reflect the old value.  Of course, the value in the environment might not change until after the script completed, not sure.

I'm running the script and then using the up arrow to edit the command line if that makes any difference, it doesn't seem to though.

Comment: Seems as if it takes some finite amount of time for the SET to take effect.

Comment: Are you running your script inside a loop?

Comment: No, it's a one shot that takes a directory path as input and calculates the CRC of each file in that directory and creates (or updates) an existing file in that directory with the CRC information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `%1%` as an environment variable because `%1` is a command line replaceable parameter.

To `set/change` and `display` a variable within parentheses or a loop you need

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

and use `echo !myvar!`

Comment: If I replace %1% with %1 I still have the same problem.

Comment: See the second part of my answer

Comment: I'm not in a loop, but I think you are pointing me in the right direction. Any complicated construct, such as my if/else would result in expansion before execution.  

I modified the script to use setlocal enabledelayedexpansion and use !myvar! to reference the variable while local is active. After these checks, I am out of the if/else, I do a endlocal, and my variable is set appropriately thereafter. 
Thanks